# How can we reply to part of a message using Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

In Thunderbird, when I highlight some text in an email and hit Reply, it trims the email chain to just the selection. That is the desired behavior. This is really useful for focusing emails when certain elements need to be split out, saves others from having to dig through entire chains to find colored text for the relevant part, and cuts out all the junk that accumulates in long chains.

How can I get the same functionality in Outlook 365?

Currently in Outlook, I have to select and copy the snippet before hitting reply, then delete the entire message in the reply before pasting the snippet. I lose the quote headers that identify who I'm replying to, so it looks awkward with the pasted text floating there. I also lose my signature. If I want to keep the quote headers and sig, I have to manually delete all the text I don't want in the reply. This is even more difficult when double/triple-click selects don't work as expected within email bodies.

Comment: There is not a built-in method to do this in Outlook. Outlook does have full macro support though, so you could probably write a macro to do this.

Comment: It is not feasible to realize this using the built-in features in Outlook. You may consider submit this feedback to Outlook UserVoice forum.https://outlook.uservoice.com/